# How to process array key in IFormCollection

Tags: json, api, rest, asp.net-core, http-post

I have a method that receives an object of type IFormCollection because I need to process files.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("StoreData")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StoreDataX(IFormCollection obj)
    {
      var item = FormCollectionToJson(obj);
      var id = this.Service.SaveDynamicData(item, "");

      return StatusCode(200, JObject.FromObject(new
      {
        message = "Registration included and workflow started."
      }));
    }
```

I convert the IFormCollection keys to a JObject

```
private JObject FormCollectionToJson(IFormCollection obj)
    {
      dynamic json = new JObject();

      if (obj.Keys.Any())
      {
        foreach (string key in obj.Keys)
        {
          var value = obj[key][0];
          json.Add(key, value);
        }
      }
      return json;
    }
```

But I am not able to do the conversion when I receive an array, how could I handle this type of data?

[Postman Request]
[image]

return of `FormCollectionToJson`

```
{
  "companies[0]": "1-1"
}
```

Expected return

```
{
  "companies": [
    "1-1"
  ]
}
```

Where am I going wrong? How to process the array or how to send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store array in the JObject, you could use the [JArray Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) to represent a Json array.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormCollection obj)
    {
        var item = FormCollectionToJson(obj);
        return StatusCode(200, JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            message = "Registration included and workflow started."
        }));
    }
    private JObject FormCollectionToJson(IFormCollection obj)
    {
        dynamic json = new JObject();
        if (obj.Keys.Any())
        {
            foreach (string key in obj.Keys)
            {   //check if the value is an array                 
                if (obj[key].Count > 1)
                {
                    JArray array = new JArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < obj[key].Count; i++)
                    {
                        array.Add(obj[key][i]);
                    }
                    json.Add(key, array);
                }
                else
                {
                   var value = obj[key][0];
                    json.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
```

The test result as below:

[image]

[image]